# Difference between By and MobileBy

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I have just noticed in an example [here](https://github.com/appium/java-workshop/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/test/workshop/AndroidNativeTest.java) that there are two options of defining locator when working with mobile applications: `By` and `MobileBy`. I was only aware of regular `By`and simple Google search didn't reveal too much information about `MobileBy`. Would be great to get some clue about what is the difference between these ones and when (if at all) the usage of `MobileBy` is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

MobileBy is optimised for MobileUIs mainly for Android and IOS instead of the generic By for mainly web locators. Read through [the java docs](http://appium.github.io/java-client/), hope this helps.